# How do you share a variable/really anything between two voids?

Tags: java, android, variables

I am wondering how to "share" things from one void to another. I have two voids: One called "Setup" and one called "NextQuestionAnswer". I have a variable in "Setup" and I need to access it from the "NextQuestionAnswer" void. I've seen other questions like this but none seem to help. Here is my code that I'm trying to achieve.

My problem is that I can't declare a TextView as a global variable because it doesn't accept public or static.

```
    public void setup() {
      ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>(); 
      ArrayList<String> correctanswers = new ArrayList<String>();

    TextView question = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.textboxquestion));
      RadioButton ac1 = (RadioButton)(findViewById(R.id.radiobuttona));
      RadioButton ac2 = (RadioButton)(findViewById(R.id.radiobuttonb));
      RadioButton ac3 = (RadioButton)(findViewById(R.id.radiobuttonc));
      RadioButton ac4 = (RadioButton)(findViewById(R.id.radiobuttond));
    }

    public void NextQuestionAnswer() {

    question.setText("something here"); ---THIS IS THE LINE THAT I WANT TO BE ABLE TO DO

}
```

Comment: Declare the variable globally under the class.

Comment: I know I am trying to shout in a hurricane, but I've got to continue my one man crusade against the "global variable" disease infecting StackOverflow.  All of the answers on here call class fields "global variables".  In programming, accuracy matters or why do we bother?  A global variable has application wide scope and has a life time equal to the application.  All of these answers refer to class fields or "class level variables".  They are not global.  it matters because it is confusing learners who are told to create a global variable and then read about the evils of globals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not access variable declare in one function in another function, so you have to declare it at class level . Please declare it before `onCreate()` Method, so you can access it.

Example.

```
public class Test extends Activity 
{
    private TextView textView = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is NOT a global variable.  With 16.8k, you should be striving more for accuracy.  This is a class field.

Answer (score 1):

You can put one global variable in your class and use that in your 2 methods.

Comment: Yes, but how would I do that with a TextView. It doesn't accept public or static.

Answer (score 0):

create variable as global variable

local variable access is only with in method itself

Answer (score 0):

This is just a thought:

If both methods are in same class why dont you use global variable?
If one method is in different class, use global variable with getter/setter (assuming the variables are not public)

Answer (score 0):

```
 private String textValue = null;   
 public void setup() {
     ...
     setTextValue("value");
     ...
 }

 public void NextQuestionAnswer() {

    question.setText(getTextValue());

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
TextView tv;//global declaration

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)
}  

  public void setup() {
         //tv can be accessed here also
   }

  public void NextQuestionAnswer() {
   tv.setText("my text"); //set yout text value

  }

}
```

When you declare it as a class variable can accessed through out the class.

If you declare the variable inside a method it is available locally only to that method.

Local variables are stored on the stack. Instance and static variables are stored on the heap.

Comment: This is NOT a global variable.  With 2.8k, you should be striving more for accuracy.  This is a class field.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it private or also you can make that public

```
private TextView question
    onCreate
    {
    question = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.textboxquestion));
    }      
    public void setup() {
          ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();
          ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>(); 
          ArrayList<String> correctanswers = new ArrayList<String>();


          RadioButton ac1 = (RadioButton)(findViewById(R.id.radiobuttona));
          RadioButton ac2 = (RadioButton)(findViewById(R.id.radiobuttonb));
          RadioButton ac3 = (RadioButton)(findViewById(R.id.radiobuttonc));
          RadioButton ac4 = (RadioButton)(findViewById(R.id.radiobuttond));
        }

        public void NextQuestionAnswer() {

        question.setText("something here"); ---THIS IS THE LINE THAT I WANT TO BE ABLE TO DO

    }
```